# wrap span's extra text to next line

Tags: javascript, css, text, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap the extra text to the next line using `overflow-wrap: break-word` but the problem is when you click, `span` moves down to next line then the extra text breaks on that next line.

I want the yellow text 'BlaBla:' to be on the same line as the text 'sometextssomet...', however I want the 'sometextssomet...' text to have the `overflow-wrap: break-word;` applied to it inside of the `<p>` element.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {

  let name = document.createElement("p");
  name.className = 'Name'
  name.innerHTML = 'BlaBla: '
  name.style = `height:40px; color: #f4c41f`

  document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].appendChild(name)

  let text = document.createElement("span");
  text.innerHTML = `sometextssometextssometextssometextssometexts`
  text.style = `overflow-wrap: break-word; font-size:14px; color: #ffffff; background: none; `

  document.getElementsByClassName('Name')[0].appendChild(text)
})
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main0"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then there are a few things here to change. First, the `<p>` has a margin applied to it by default, which is causing this vertical "jump" that you are noticing when it's added to your document. Try adding the following CSS to address this issue:

```
p {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Also, consider adding a `<span>` to the created `<p>` for both the yellow "blabla" text, and the white text to allow the `break-word` CSS rule to work as required by doing the following:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  
  // Create span for each piece of text with different styling
  let blabla = document.createElement("span"); 
  blabla.innerText = 'BlaBla:' 
  blabla.style = 'color:yellow'

  let text = document.createElement("span");
  text.innerText = `sometextssometextssometextssometextssometexts` 

  // Append both span elements to the paragraph where word spacing should
  // be applied
  let name = document.createElement("p");      
  name.appendChild(blabla);
  name.appendChild(text);
  
  document.querySelector('.main').appendChild(name)
})
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px; 
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:0;
  display:block;
  color:white;
}
 
span {     
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main0"></div>
```

Comment: @adamwest strange - it might be the browser you're using - I just updated the snippet , does that work for you?

Comment: nope, I'm using chrome v70, it also doesn't work with firefox.

Comment: interesting (seems to work for me) - what's failing? it's doing nothing? or, is it just not rendering in the way you expect?

Comment: nothing changed, result it's exactly same with my first code

Comment: ok, in your origianl it seemed that the yellow "BlaBla" text was weirdly overlapping the white text - my solution correctly stacks the "BlaBla" and white text to avoid that overlap. Perhaps i've mis understood your question - can you please clarify?

Comment: I couldn't explain it well, sorry for that. I want it to be like this: [link](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/11/27/dde5d6adea0dc8203caf7d7f7fbae661-full.png). although still the results are same:  my code: [link](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/11/27/41089d031f3d4503800861e3fcdb7e59-full.png) yours: [link](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/11/27/7457db0e4ec5522f9821307801486e66-full.png)